# CurrentPrincipal is null in IErrorHandler.ProvideFault?

Tags: c#, wcf, ierrorhandler, current-principal

I have created a IErrorHandler to handle all Exception in the WCF service. The problem is that as soon as I get to the ProvideFault method the Thread.CurrentPrincipal is null? It is poroperly set in the servicemethod?

The evaluationContext.Properties["Principal"] is set in the  IAuthorizationPolicy.Evaluate based on IncomingMessageHeader.

I suspect that the IErrorHandler.ProvideFault is executed on another thread.

Is there any way to get the value of Thread.CurrentPrincipal to the  IErrorHandler.ProvideFault?

Comment: I think it runs asynchronously in different thread. did you tried using `OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext` ?

Comment: Did not know about it. I found the information I need here : Operationcontext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.AuthorizationContext.Properties[0].Value.CurrentPersonId. Is this safe to use?